# How to numerically solve an eigenvalue problem of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem

I am trying to replicate a result from a [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Maria-Luneva/publication/225240084_Evolution_of_a_turbulent_burst/links/56ced7f308aeb52500c5f06b/Evolution-of-a-turbulent-burst.pdf) (Eq. 36).

There, the authors numerically solved an eigenvalue problem:

$\frac{d}{d\zeta}\left[ \alpha_1 f^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{df}{d\zeta}\right] + (1-\mu) \zeta \frac{df}{d\zeta} + 2\mu f - \frac{c_1}{\alpha_1} f^{\frac{3}{2}}=0$,

$\frac{d f^{\frac{3}{2}} (0)}{d\zeta} = 0, f(1)=0,  \frac{d f^{\frac{3}{2}} (1)}{d\zeta} = 0. $

Just to be clear, $f$ is just a function of $\zeta$. $\mu$ is a parameter of the ODE. It determines if a solution exists according to the authors. $\alpha_1, c_1$ are constants.

The authors claimed that such an eigenvalue problem could be easily solved numerically but I do not know how I should approach.

Could you please advice?

Comment: In a boundary value problem, you guess the missing parameters in the initial state, Thus it is no burden to guess some additional parameters. If necessary, formulate the eigenvalue as a third, constant component of the state. // Note that as the equation is not linear in $f$, this is not really an eigenvalue problem.

Comment: $\alpha_1$, $c_1$, and $\mu$ are known constants?

Comment: @user7530 Yes. 

"... we arrive at a classical situation of a nonlinear eigenvalue problem: we have to construct a non-trivial solution to Eq. I (the one I posted) that satisfies (the boundary) conditions, and, moreover, to determine the value of parameter $\mu$ for which such a solution exists. It can be shown that the solution of this eigenvalue problem is unique; it can be easily solved numerically."

My goal is actually to find the value of $\mu$ that gives non-trivial solutions to this ODE. I am not sure how to proceed...

Comment: @user7530
Source: Barenblatt, Nonlinear dynamics and turbulence (selected chapters),  p.54

The book can be found here. https://libgen.is/book/index.php?md5=E4EBBED8B7DDBCA94F1479E99ABB1DF4

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks for your response. I am not necessarily sure about the terminology but the author (Barenblatt, a mathematician) says "... we arrive at a classical situation of a nonlinear eigenvalue problem" when he considered this ODE. In the paper and the book, he numerically solves for $f(\zeta)$ for a specific case of $\alpha_1$ and $c_1/\alpha_1$. I'm not sure how he did it.

Comment: Yes, there is some association to eigenvalues as a parameter that makes the BVP non-trivially solvable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $f$ and $\mu$ are unknown but everything else is a known constant: you can solve for $f$ and $\mu$ using a shooting method.

1. Write everything in terms of $g(\zeta) = f(\zeta)^{3/2}$ instead of $f$, so that the boundary conditions become ordinary Dirichlet and Neumann conditions.
2. Next, cut up the $\zeta$-interval $[0,1]$ into a 1D grid of spacing $h = \frac{1}{N}$ and let $g_i = g(i/N)$. Larger choices of $N$ will yield a more accurate answer at higher computational cost.
3. Discretize your ODE onto the grid by expressing differential operators as finite differences. Since the ODE is second-order, you will get a set of discrete equations involving three consecutive values of $g$:
   $$L(g_{i}, g_{i+1}, g_{i+2},\mu) = 0.$$
4. Guess a value of $\mu$.
5. Since you know $g_N$ and $g_{N-1}$ from the boundary conditions, you can solve for $g_{N-2}$, and then iteratively solve for all other values of $g_i$.
6. Does $\frac{g_1-g_0}{h}\approx 0$? If so, your value of $\mu$ happened to be correct. If not, change your guess and repeat step 5. There are several reasonable strategies here: you might start with a coarse sampling of different $\mu$ guesses and then refine the search near where $|g'(0)|$ is smallest, or start with one guess and incrementally update $\mu$ in the direction that decreases $|g'(0)|$.

Comment: This gave me some ideas. I'll definitely try! Just wanted to say quick thanks!

Comment: This substitution will be numerically singular at the boundaries, as the terms that are linear in $f$ now have $g^{2/3}$. The first derivative is also directly singular. Note that $f=0$ is a solution, but has to be excluded.

Comment: This seemed like a right path to pursue but I got stuck again. Because of the given boundary condition, it is natural to try the shooting method from $\zeta=1 \Leftrightarrow i = N$. The problem is that the step to find $g_{N-2}$ would include terms like $1/g(x)$ which is singular at the boundary ($\zeta=1$). The same issue exists for $f_{N-2}$ even if I decide to keep using $f(\zeta)$.

Comment: This is basically what @LutzLehmann commented. How should I handle this divergence? Should I try the shooting method, starting at $\zeta=0$ and guessing $f(\zeta=0)$? That cannot be right.